# Is okay to implement Modernizr with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modernizr, html5shiv

Is it OK to implement Modernizr with Twitter Bootstrap?

I'm currently using Bootstrap with Google's html5shiv and I wanted to know if I can use Modernizr instead or is it overkill just to get HTML5 elements activated for older IE browsers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you decide to implement CSP at some point you should be aware that, while Bootstrap works fine with it, [Modenizr fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532234/modernizr-causes-content-security-policy-csp-violation-errors). This means that your XSS protection options will be limited if you choose to use it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Modernizr is a test suite that adds *feature detection* via classes applied to the body tag. It includes HTML5Shi(v|m) to add older browser compatibility. You don't need Modernizr just to style new tags in older browsers.

That said, **it is OK to include Modernizr with Twitter Bootstrap**. You can even get an auto-generated H5BP template with Bootstrap and Modernizr included at [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/).

Comment: I'm using `bootstrap 2.3.2` and using `modernizr` distorts everything. Any solution ?

Comment: @coding_idiot you should post a new question with your specific issue(s).

Comment: let me try to replicate on jsFiddle and then I'll post the question.