# Can't get a jQuery plugin wroked - Direction Aware Hover Effect

Tags: jquery, plugins

I did the same as the tutorial yet I can't get it work.
Basically, It's a jQuery plugin that detects the direction that you're coming from with the mouse.

This is the tutorial (Codrops):
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

And my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hk73k/1/

**You'll see that there are 3 li's, but only one alert message. So I guess it's something with the JS code.**

```
.da-thumbs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.da-thumbs li a,
.da-thumbs li a img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

$(function () {
    $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each(function () {
        alert('I should be shown 2 more times!');
        $(this).hoverdir();
    });
});
```

I'm so frustrated. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the JS errors in your jsfiddle console window. That will help you understand the real problem if there is any.

You need to add moderenizr JS to your fiddle.

Here is the fiddle for that: `jsfiddle.net/hk73k/2/`

Comment: That's not the solution! :/

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan the jsfiddle link needs modernizr references. It is throwing outright reference error . After that there are cross domain related errors. Fixing these two may resolve the problem. Why do think it's not a solution?

Comment: In fact, adding modernizr  reference to the jsfiddle link fixes the problem. Here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/hk73k/2/

Comment: Thanks DevPat. I am using the bootstrap framework, will it conflict anything if I'm adding modernizr? Actually, better for is finding a way to make this code work W/o modernizr. Is that possible?

Comment: Ooh, sorry for the misunderstanding! You're right! :) @DevPat :)

Comment: @user3121234 There will be no conflicts in using bootstrap with modernizr. You can read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209478/is-okay-to-implement-modernizr-with-twitter-bootstrap). However, the plugin in your jsfidle link uses only one property of `Modernizr` object i.e., `csstransitions`. If you don't want to use `Modernizr` then the plugin needs to do browser sniffing and set the value as `true` or `false` based on browser. Read more about this at [Modernizr documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/).